# Type of "Int -> Bool" ,"Int-> Bool -> Int","Int-> String -> Int－> Bool"

Tags: ios, swift

There is a func:

```
 func (first: Int) -> Int -> Bool -> String {

    return  ?
 }
```

How to write the return value?
I'm so confused about the return type like of the func above.

Comment: what it does is over complicate things and should be re-written probably

Comment: @Fonix - this is part of the functional programming support that Swift has built-in

Comment: @Cristik doesnt make it any less ugly to read / use. `f(1)(2)(true)` kinda breaks the whole "functions should read like sentences" that obj-c and swift try to get devs to use (with good reason). could be a good reason for this but im sure it could be avoidable

Comment: @Fonix there are situations where functional programming concepts generates smaller, more readable, and more testable code. It might not be the case for the example in this question (anyhow not without context), though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say you define a closure

```
let closure: Int -> Bool
```

once the closure type is known (type of parameters and return type), writing it is quite easy, you name the list of parameters, followed by keyword `in` and then the function's body (with a return at the end, if the function return type isn't `Void` (a.k.a `()`)

```
// closure that returns if an integer is even
closure = { integer in 
    return integer %2 == 0
}
```

In your case, `Int -> Int -> Bool -> String` means

- a function that takes an Int as parameter and returns

  - a function that takes an Int as parameter and returns

    - a function that takes a
      Bool as parameter and returns

      - a String

A way to write that in code :

```
func prepareForSum(first: Int) -> Int -> Bool -> String {
    return  { secondInteger in
        return { shouldSumIntegers in

        var result: Int
        // for the sake of example
        // if boolean is true, we sum
        if shouldSumIntegers {
            result = first + secondInteger
        } else {
            // otherwise we take the max
            result = max(first, secondInteger)
        }

        return String(result)
    }
 }
```

now you can use it like that

```
let sumSixteen = prepareForSum(16) // type of sumSixteen is Int -> Bool -> String

let result1 = sumSixteen(3)(true) // result1 == "19"
let result2 = sumSixteen(26)(false) // result2 == "26"
```

Answer (score 9):

Read from right to left when it comes into parsing function/closure returns. The right outermost one is the return type, and you can place the rest into parentheses.

Thus, your function declaration is equivalent to

```
func (first: Int) -> ((Int) -> ((Bool) -> String))
```

and to

```
func (first: Int)(_ second: Int)(_ third: Bool) -> String
```

though this form will no longer be supported in Swift 3.0 (thanks @Andrea for the heads up).

This is known as [function currying](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introduction-to-function-currying-in-swift). You function returns a function that takes an `Int` as argument and returns another function that takes a `Bool` as parameter and returns a `String`. This way you can easily chain
function calls.

So the body of your method must return the first function in the list, one that has the following signature:

```
func ((Int) -> ((Bool) -> String))
```

You can then call it like this:

```
f(1)(2)(true)
```

Comment: I thought currying was when you have a function taking multiple parameters, and you transform it into a function that returns a function that returns a function (... and so on for each argument). There was no mention of a function with multiple parameters in the question.

Comment: A currying transform can end up generating the function signature in discussion. The currying information are there to explain how you can end up with functions that return functions that return functions, etc.

Comment: Currying is cool unfortunately will be removed in Swift 3.0 as per swift evolution list on  github https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution

Comment: Thanks @Andrea for the heads up, I have updated the answer with this info.